# How to sort non-numerical objects in Java when only some relationships are known?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of items:

```
[foo, bar, baz, boo, abc, xyz]
```

**Some** of these items want to be sorted in a specific order:

```
foo after abc
xyz before baz
```

The order of the other items does not matter as long as all given rules are respected.

Here are some of the possible sorted orders:

```
[abc, foo, xyz, baz, bar, boo]
[abc, xyz, foo, baz, bar, boo]
[abc, foo, bar, boo, xyz, baz]
[xyz, baz, bar, boo, abc, foo]
```

Using a `Comparator` does not seem to work, as it is possible to engineer a list that will cause it to fail. For instance, if our compare method looks like this:

```
list.sort((a, b) -> {
    if (a.isAfter(b)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.isBefore(b)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

And we run it against `[foo, bar, baz, boo, abc, xyz]`, the method will do as follows:

```
Comparing 'bar' to 'foo': no rule present -> 0
Comparing 'baz' to 'bar': no rule present -> 0
Comparing 'boo' to 'baz': no rule present -> 0
Comparing 'abc' to 'boo': no rule present -> 0
Comparing 'xyz' to 'abc': no rule present -> 0
```

The Comparator will run, but it will just spit out the same list you started with. It seems that for a Comparator to work correctly, you need to know the relationship between any two items in the list, not just some of them.

Knowing this, one solution would be to move all elements that have rules to a separate list, sort that one, and then merge it with the rest of the elements. This way we *do* know the relationship between all the items we are comparing. However, for this to work, you have to create separate lists **for every single rule**. Otherwise there is a likelihood that you could run into the exact same problem again:

```
[foo, bar, baz, boo, abc, xyz] // original
[foo, baz, abc, xyz] // elements with rules
[foo, baz, abc, xyz] // elements with rules **after comparator**
[foo, baz, abc, xyz, bar, boo] // merged with the rest, rules not satisfied
```

Creating lists for every single rule that might appear is not very elegant. Is there another sorter I can use that accommodates for the kind of behavior I am looking for?

Comment: Comparator requires a total ordering, so that wouldn't work. You are looking for something like a topological sort.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then just impose a total ordering, and sort using that: abc = 0, xyz = 0,  all the other ones = 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner: it's really easy to enforce/impose an arbitrary total ordering *so long as none of the rules contradict each other*. Just put everything not covered by a rule at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final implementation I used; a bit of a mashup from things people have suggested here. The data is structured as a list of nodes, where each node might want to be **before** or **after** another node. Here is the pseudo code for how it works:

```
for nodeA in nodes:
    for nodeB in nodes:
        if nodeA should be after nodeB:
            nodeA.dependencies.add(nodeB)

// sort nodes based on their score
nodes.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Node::getScore))


interface Node:
    dependencies := []

    keyValue := -1
    isComputingKeyValue := false

    getScore():
        // avoid needless recursion, return cached value if available
        if keyValue > -1:
            return keyValue

        max := 0

        // if this flag is true, we have a circular dependency
        if isComputingKeyValue:
            throw CircularDependencyException

        isComputingKeyValue = true

        // calculate the maximum score among dependencies
        for node in dependencies:
            if node.getScore() >= max:
                // set this node's score 1 larger
                max = node.getScore() + 1

        // spit out this node's score
        isComputingKeyValue = false
        keyValue = max
        return max
```

Now as to why it works. The basic idea is that you get each node to know what index it has in its branch of the dependency tree. For instance, if A knows that it must go after B and C, then its index/score is `max(score of A, score of B) + 1`. If something has no dependencies, it simply has an index/score of zero.

Because we now know the relationship between each element in the list, we can use the `Comparator` class to sort the list.

This implementation is quite nice, as it A) catches circular dependencies very gracefully and B) only has one nested for loop (unless you count recursion as for loops). With some caching you can even avoid unnecessary recursion, as the code shows.

Thank you to everyone who posted their ideas, they gave me the motivation and inspiration to try this one!

Comment: Doesn't that mean that every node without rule will be at the beginning of the array after the sorting algorithm ?

Comment: @LoïcFrance Precisely: every node that does not have a rule goes at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is to "compile" all of the rules into a single list. For example, the two rules mentioned above would generate this list:

["abc", "foo", "xyz", "baz"]

(or ["xyz", "baz", "abc", "foo"]. You'll get different answers but the rules will still be followed).

You will always be able to do this unless there's a cycle of rules, in which case they are impossible to follow. ("abc goes before def, def goes before ghi, ghi goes before abc" is an example of an impossible ruleset).

But if they aren't impossible, then you can compile them into a list — basically all of the named terms in rank order. Your comparator is just the position in that list, and a negative number if the item is not in the list.

With Java 8/9 goodness, you can write that comparator easily like so:

```
List<String> rules = List.of("abc", "foo", "xyz", "baz");
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing((String s) -> rules.indexOf(s));
```

And then you're off to the races. This comparator sorts the items by their index using a *key extraction function* — basically a function that turns the value into another value, and then sorts by that value. Since list.indexOf() returns -1 for items not mentioned in the rules, and zero or higher for items mentioned in the rules, non-mentioned items will always go at the front, followed by items mentioned in the rules in rule order.

(If you'd prefer items not mentioned in the rules to go at the end, then your key extractor function needs to use contains, and return Integer.MAX_VALUE for items not in the list.)

Since Java's sorting algorithm TimSort is a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting algorithm, all of the values with indexes of -1 will be returned in the same order they were in before the list was sorted.

**Update: How to "compile" the rules into a list**

This can be done by taking advantage of the stable sort algorithm. Add each item mentioned in a rule into a list, and then sort that list once by each individual rule in isolation. For example: the rule "foo after abc" would be a key extractor function that returns 0 for abc, 1 for foo, and Integer.MAX_VALUE for everything else.

Once you've sorted the list once for each rule, you need to check each rule again in a single pass to ensure that all them still hold. (If any don't, you have an impossible ruleset.)

Comment: While this is a very clever way of doing it, this method could get quite complicated if you have rules that contain duplicate keys, for instance: <foo after abc>, <baz before bar>, <bar after foo>. You would need another clever sorter to sort the list of rules :)

Comment: You should be able to compile the ruleset by taking advantage of stable sort: put all of the rule terms in the list, and then sort the list once for each rule. Then at the end iterate through the list once making sure each rule still holds: this is necessary to check for impossible rule sets. (Lots of sorts sounds slow but shouldn't be — it's the same total number of comparisons as one sort with a compound comparison.)

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple solutions for this type of problem.

One of the solutions would be to do the sort manually : you iterate over the array and when you see a `foo`, you search in the remaining array for all `abc` and place them behind (or in the reverse order : when you see a `abc`, you search for all `foo` in the already passed array and place them ahead).

Another solution would be to do multiple sorts (one for every rule, in this case 2), and each time create an array containing pairs [value, number] where the number depends on the value from the original array. For the first rule, we could have :

- `foo` => 1
- `abc` => 0
- all other values => the last used value, or 0.

So the array `[foo, bar, baz, boo, abc, xyz]` will be translated into
`[(foo,1), (bar,1), (baz,1), (boo,1), (abc,0), (xyz,0)]`.
When we sort it using the numbers in the pairs, we get the following array :
`[(abc,0), (xyz,0), (foo,1), (bar,1), (baz,1), (boo,1)]`.
which is sorted.

Now if we apply the second rule (`xyz`=>0, `baz`=>1), we get the following array :
`[(abc,0), (xyz,0), (foo,0), (bar,0), (baz,1), (boo,1)]`.
You now have a sorted array.

You can improve this by using Tuples of [number of rules]+1 elements and assign all the values the first time, and apply the `sort` function once for every rule, choosing the element of the tuple to sort on each time.

depending on the number of rules and the size of the array, the first method can be better than the second.

If you have a lot of rules and a small array, I think I would prefer the first method.
On the contrary, if you have a few rules and a big array, I would suggest the second method.

the reason for this choice is simple : If you have big array, the second method will rely on the `sort` function integrated in the language, which is faster. On the contrary, if you have a lot of rules, the second method will imply calling the sort function a lot of times, where the first method will cost about the same time no matter the number of rules

Comment: While perhaps not the fastest, your second method makes a lot more logical sense in my head than some of the other solutions offered here. I'll take another look this weekend and decide on a final answer.

Comment: It's been almost a week now. Did you take the time to try this method ?

Comment: I actually did, it's a slight variation of your method, but in essence it's the same thing. Is it the fastest method? Probably not. Lots and lots of looping. But it works. As for marking this as the answer, technically all methods proposed here would work. I'm not qualified enough to choose the best one though :)

Comment: @Campbell Is the variation you used specific to your application ? If not, could you explain it ? I'm interested to know what algorithm you used and if it is usable outside your application.

Comment: I did my best! You can find my answer somewhere on this page.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this...

For `Comparator` to work, you'll need to make a new class. This class represents all possible values of objects in your list. It is then up to you to implement the 
`compare()` method, as part of your contract when you implement the `Comparator` interface.

```
class AlphaListItem implements Comparator<String> 
{
    @Override
    public static int compare(String a, String b) 
    {
        //check if a or b is 'abc' or 'xyz' - if so, a or b respectively has value 999
        //check if a or b is 'foo' or 'baz' - if so, a or b respectively has value 50
        //check if a or b is anything else - if so, a or b respectively has value 0
        //compare using their corresponding values, return -1 (a is less than b), 0 (a is equal to b), 1 (a is greater than b)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try defining and using a Java `Enum`. This is only reasonable if your list items are bounded - that is, there is a finite number of items possible in this list. It is not clear from your question whether this is the case.
The ordering rules can be implemented in your enum, as enums have an inherent ordering depending how you define the enum.
Enums also have a very useful `compareTo()` method, where you can compare one with another.

In either case, you'll need to use a sorting algorithm. Exactly how you compare the objects is up to you (enum, comparator, etc...).

One final way to trivialize this problem is to use a logic based programming language like Prolog. You'll have just two predicates, and the rest of it is easy...

Comment: "...a finite number of items possible in this list". Unfortunately not. The objects in the list are really pieces of input data, unknown until runtime.